# How to delete an element in list in react?

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to do a simple toDo app with react. I couldnt do how to delete an element in list. Here my code; first state:

```
class AppForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { items: [] , text:''};
    this.onChangeHandler=this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)
    this.submitHandler=this.submitHandler.bind(this)
  }
```

//setting input value to the text in state

```
 onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      text: e.target.value
    });
  };
```

//pushing text item of the state to the items

```
    submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const arrayItem = {
            text: this.state.text,    
        };
    
    this.setState(state => ({
        items: state.items.concat(arrayItem),
        text: ''
    }));
 }
```

here the problem area. I also tried splice but couldnt.

```
 deleteItem=(index)=>{

    let todos= this.state.items.filter(todo => index !== todo.key)
    this.setState({
        items : todos
    })    
 }
```

then rendering..

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>toDo App</h1>

        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <label>Type the task you want to do!</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.onChangeHandler} value={this.state.text}/>
        </form>

        <ul>
            {this.state.items.map((item,index) =>{
                return (
                <li key={index}> {item.text}
                    <p onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this,index)}> X </p>
                </li>
                )
            })}
        </ul>    
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AppForm;
```

Comment: If you are currently learning React from scratch, I would highly suggest you avoid class components and stick to functional components and hooks. They need less code and are, in my opinion, more clear to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Splice is the answer.

First, I create a copy of your state array. Then splice it using the index clicked. Then set setState with the spliced array.

deleteItem=(index)=>{

```
let todos= [...this.state.items]

todos.splice(index, 1)

this.setState({
    items : todos
})
```

}

Comment: OP is not setting the `id`, So how could he delete the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteItem = (index) => {
    this.setState(({items}) => { 
        return {items: [...items.filter(todo => index !== todo.key)]};
    })    
}
```

Comment: OP is not setting the `id`, So how could he delete the element.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're not setting the `key` anywhere when you are inserting in array. It is not at all recommended to use `index` as key in array. It should be unique.

```
const arrayItem = {
      text: this.state.text,
      id: uuid()
};
```

So I've added the `uuid` and compared with the `id` of the element.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-glitter-0b52h?file=/src/App.js)

**uuid**

```
 // UNIQUE KEY GENERATOR
    function uuidv4() {
      return "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx".replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = (Math.random() * 16) | 0,
          v = c == "x" ? r : (r & 0x3) | 0x8;
        return v.toString(16);
      });
    }
    
    export default uuidv4;
```

**React component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import uuid from "./uuid";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { items: [], text: "" };
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.submitHandler = this.submitHandler.bind(this);
  }

  //setting input value to the text in state

  onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      text: e.target.value
    });
  };
  //pushing text item of the state to the items

  submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const arrayItem = {
      text: this.state.text,
      id: uuid()
    };

    this.setState((state) => ({
      items: state.items.concat(arrayItem),
      text: ""
    }));
  };
  deleteItem = (key) => {
    let todos = this.state.items.filter((todo) => key !== todo.id);
    this.setState({
      items: todos
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>toDo App</h1>

        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <label>Type the task you want to do!</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
            value={this.state.text}
          />
        </form>

        <ul>
          {this.state.items.map((item) => {
            return (
              <li key={item.id}>
                {item.text}
                <p onClick={() => this.deleteItem(item.id)}> X </p>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```